# How to create a TLS pool in go

Tags: go, tcp, connection-pooling, pool, tls1.2

I currently have an issue with Golang 1.7.1
My purpose is to create a pool with TLS connections from lib "crypto/tls"

My purpose is to forward stdin entry to the network via TLS. I am reading the stdin with `reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)` and loop at it. before the loop I tried to create the pool.

I followed the TCP pool sample from : https://github.com/fatih/pool

Sample from my code :

```
factory    := func() (tls.Conn, error) {
    log.Println("**************  factory start :) :() **************")
    conn, err :=    tls.Dial("tcp", "discover.logs.ovh.com:12202" , &tls.Config{
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,   })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println("**************  factory stop :) **************")
    return *conn, err
}
p, err := NewChannelPool(3, 10, factory)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
log.Println("NewReader done")
for {
    line, overflow, err := reader.ReadLine()
    if err == io.EOF {
        /*err = p.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }*/
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    ......
    ......
    ......
    conn, err := p.Get()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    bytes, err := conn.Write(databytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    conn.Close()

}
```

The main difference between tls / tcp lib (apart from the secure part) is the Dial return `*tls.Conn`
and tcp `tcp.Conn`

So I thought I was doing well by returning *conn, I return the object pointed by the pointer.

I always end up open by this error when I start the second connection:

> journald-gateway_1  | 2016/12/13 16:19:20 socat[15] E write(6, 0x55fc5a73db80, 1006): Broken pipe

Any Idea?

Thank you for reading me.

Comment: You can't copy a tls.Conn, always use a pointer.

Comment: Thank for your answer. The func Dial(network, addr string, config *Config) (*Conn, error)   , now it make sense why i can't return return *conn, err . Thank you